# Is a Necromancy wizard's hit point maximum reduced when they gives hit points to his homunculus from the Create Homunculus spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, hit-points, necromancy

In the D&D 5e campaign I'm playing in, my School of Necromancy wizard just gained the spell [*create homunculus*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-homunculus) (from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 152). Part of the spell's description reads (emphasis mine):

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can spend up to half your Hit Dice if the homunculus is on the same plane of existence as you. When you do so, roll each die and add your Constitution modifier to it. **Your hit point maximum is reduced by the total, and the homunculus’s hit point maximum and current hit points are both increased by it.** This process can reduce you to no lower than 1 hit point, and the change to your and the homunculus’s hit points ends when you finish your next long rest. The reduction to your hit point maximum can’t be removed by any means before then, except by the homunculus’s death.

However, the [School of Necromancy wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofNecromancy)'s [Inured to Undeath](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#InuredtoUndeath-448) feature (PHB, p. 119) states that my hit point maximum can't be reduced.

Would this allow me to grant hit points to my homunculus without my necromancer's hit point maximum being reduced?

Comment: Possibly related: [Does a Vampire's Bite heal it even if Maximum Hit Points aren't reduced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111499/does-a-vampires-bite-heal-it-even-if-maximum-hit-points-arent-reduced)

Answer (score 22):

## No, your necromancer's hit point maximum is not reduced.

Conversely, you can raise your homonculus' hit point maximum without your necromancer reducing his hit point maximum.

*Inured to Undeath* states

> your hit point maximum can't be reduced

This is a very straightforward effect. Since specific beats general and this rules specifically says that it's not possible for your hit point maximum to be reduced, it simply cannot happen unless an even more specific rule says so.

### Does Create Homunculus override Inured to Undeath?

We intuitively accept that *Inured to Undeath* allows you to ignore hit point maximum reductions from the attack of undead creatures such as a *Specter*. Let's look at how the *Specter* applies the hit point maximum reduction:

> its **hit point maximum is reduced by** an amount equal to the damage taken

Now lets look at how *Create Homunculus* applies the hit point maximum reduction:

> Your **hit point maximum is reduced by** the total

Both of these sentences effectively read as:

> [a creature's] **hit point maximum is reduced by** [a number]

Since they say the same thing and don't use any wording that makes us think they should override your specific ability of ignoring hit point maximum reductions, *Inured to Undeath* applies here.

*Create Homunculus* does go on to state the following:

> The reduction to your hit point maximum can’t be removed by any means before then, except by the homunculus‘s death.

That is a specific rule but it only stops you from removing the hit point maximum reduction. Since your hit points were never reduced, that is not an issue for you.

### Will my Homonculus' hit point maximum increase anyway?

Now that we know that you can ignore the hit point maximum reduction, does your homonculus still get to increase his hit point maximum?

Here are the rules that determine how large the hit point maximum exchange is supposed to be:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can spend up to half your Hit Dice if the homunculus is on the same plane of existence as you. When you do so, **roll each die and add your Constitution modifier to it**.

The bold text shows you how to calculate **the total** by which each creature's hit point maximum will change.

Let's look at the next sentence which performs the hit point maximum transfer:

> Your hit point maximum is reduced by **the total**, and the homunculus’s hit point maximum and current hit points are both increased by **it**.

Here we are applying 2 separate effects:

1. The first effect is to reduce your hit point maximum by **the total**.
2. The second effect is to reduce your hit point maximum by **it** which clearly refers to **the total**.

Note that the second effect only refers to **the total** which was calculated when you rolled the dice and not to the amount by which your hit point maximum was actually reduced. This means that getting around the hit point maximum reduction doesn't stop your homunculus from raising his hit point maximum at all.

### Official Support

This interpretation is supported by the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) as of at least version 2.5.

Comment: Completely agree with Yannick's reasoning, though can't help feeling that this is an _unintended_ result of mixing Inured to Undeath with the newer Create Homonculus spell. Probably not what was intended!

Comment: So you can increase the homunculus hp by said amount every long rest cumulatively up to infinity? Seems a little unbalanced.

Comment: @Rosco.p.coltrane No, the change to your homunculus' hitpoints ends when you finish your next long rest, as usual.

Comment: This question is now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=16): "**If a wizard with Inured to Undeath spends Hit Dice to raise the hit point maximum of a homunculus created by the *create homunculus* spell, does it still decrease the wizard’s hit point maximum?** Spending the Hit Dice affects the homunculus as described in the spell, but the wizard’s hit point maximum isn’t decreased." You may want to update your answer accordingly.