# aura of life and create homunculus

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, magic

If you are under the effects of the [*Aura of Life*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aura-of-life) spell for the entire duration of casting [*Create Homunculus*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-homunculus), how would your hit points be affected? What if you are under the effect of *Aura of Life* and choose to give up hit dice to your homunculus for the day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The caster doesn't lose HP maximum and the homunculus gains HP.

*tl;dr* [Sage Advice](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) addresses this situation through the lens of the Inured to Undeath class feature:

> **If a wizard with Inured to Undeath spends Hit Dice to raise the hit point maximum of a homunculus created by the create homunculus spell, does it still decrease the wizard’s hit point maximum?** Spending the Hit Dice affects the homunculus as described in the spell, but the wizard’s hit point maximum isn’t decreased

### The Inured to Death class feature and Aura of Life spell have the same effect to mitigate the HP max loss of buffing a homunculus.

*Create Homunculus*:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can spend up to half your Hit Dice if the homunculus is on the same plane of existence as you. When you do so, roll each die and add your Constitution modifier to it. Your hit point maximum is reduced by the total, and the homunculus’s hit point maximum and current hit points are both increased by it.

*Aura of Life*:

> Each nonhostile creature in the aura (including you) has resistance to necrotic damage, and **its hit point maximum can’t be reduced**.

Inured to Undeath:

> Beginning at 10th level, you have resistance to necrotic damage, and **your hit point maximum can’t be reduced**.

### Related Question about *create homunculus*

[Is a Necromancy wizard's hit point maximum reduced when they gives hit points to his homunculus from the Create Homunculus spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122313/is-a-necromancy-wizards-hit-point-maximum-reduced-when-they-gives-hit-points-to)